# For long headings 2nd line should be display as the 75% of first line in text

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have a text widget to show the headline. If I have a long headline, which breaks into two lines

```
Text(
  "Heading",
  maxLines:2,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
)
```

It works perfectly.
[image]

But my requirement is not exactly like this. For long headings, 2nd  line should be displayed as 75% of the first line if the length is long . Below I attached the expected result,

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could truncate the first line to the right length and use the rest for the second line. Place both in the [RichText Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html) and define different styles for each.

In general I would not solve this problem in the code way but talk to the author of the text if possible. This does not sound like the best practice of typography to me.